# Custom Zedgraph ToolStripMenuItem won't check when clicked

Tags: c#, zedgraph, toolstripmenu

I customize the right click menu thanks to this :

```
lineGraphControl1.ContextMenuBuilder += new ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuBuilderEventHandler(MyContextMenuBuilder);
```

And

```
private void MyContextMenuBuilder(ZedGraphControl control, ContextMenuStrip menuStrip, Point mousePt, ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuObjectState objState)
{
    // create a new menu item
    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    // This is the user-defined Tag so you can find this menu item later if necessary
    item.Name = "simple_cursor";
    // This is the text that will show up in the menu
    item.Text = "Simple Cursor";
    item.CheckOnClick = true;
    // Add a handler that will respond when that menu item is selected
    item.Click += new System.EventHandler(DisplaySimpleCursor);
    // Add the menu item to the menu
    menuStrip.Items.Add(item);
}
```

But the menu `Simple Cursor` won't check when clicked. I try to force the sender in the function `DisplaySimpleCursor()`, it doesn't work.

When I debug my app, I see that in `DisplaySimpleCursor()`, the sender's property *Checked* is set to true.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the menu is build on the heat, the `checkOnClick` means nothing since the object is destroyed (I guess) everytime the menu is hidden.

The solution was to set the property :

```
// showOneCursor is a bool describing my need and toggled on click
item.Checked = showOneCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 private bool check;
    public bool Check
    {
        get { return check; }
        set { check= value; }
    }
private void MyContextMenuBuilder(ZedGraphControl control, ContextMenuStrip menuStrip, Point mousePt, ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuObjectState objState)
{
    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    item.Name = "simple_cursor";
    item.Text = "Simple Cursor";
    item.CheckOnClick = true;
        item.Checked = Check; //add this
    item.Click += new System.EventHandler(DisplaySimpleCursor);
    menuStrip.Items.Add(item);
}


 private void DisplaySimpleCursor(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Check = false==Check;
        }
```